# WPF bind datagrid with xml returned in web response

Tags: wpf, xml, datagrid, bind

I am getting xml of this format in response from a web request, but i am unable to bind it whit data drid in wpf.

Here is my xml :

```
<population>
<name>Tram, Joshua </name>
  <id>83804</id>
  <hcp>Dr. Krueger</hcp>
  <symptoms>4</symptoms>
  <range>1/17/13 - 4/13/13</range>
  <last7>5</last7>
  <connect>41380</connect>
  <engage>5</engage>
  <daysin>160</daysin>
  <education>0.67</education>
  <recco>Encourage Education</recco>
  <name>Riess, Chuck </name>
  <id>73403</id>
  <hcp>Dr. Vockell</hcp>
  <symptoms>4</symptoms>
  <range>2/1/13 - 2/14/13</range>
  <last7>5</last7>
  <connect>41332</connect>
  <engage>5</engage>
  <daysin>179</daysin>
  <education>0.74</education>
  <recco>Encourage Tracking</recco>
  <name>Park, Teruyuki </name>
  <id>69235</id>
  <hcp>Dr. Smithen</hcp>
  <symptoms>3</symptoms>
  <range>4/3/13 - 4/13/13</range>
  <last7>5</last7>
  <connect>41384</connect>
  <engage>5</engage>
  <daysin>35</daysin>
  <education>0.15</education>
  <recco> </recco>
  </population>
```

and here is my code, i am storing it in dataset and binding with datagrid but it only shows on column not all.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();        

DataSet set = new DataSet();            

set.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream());            

return set;
```

Comment: The xml seems odd to say the least.. anyway, what have you tried? You ask about binding to WPF datagrid, but the code you provided does not show any WPF related lines...

Comment: It looks like there are tags missing from the xml. There are multiple instances of each tag (i.e. the <id>, <hcp>, <symptoms>, etc) as if they should be wrapped with another tag.

Comment: no its the actual xml returned by in response by webrequest

Comment: the issue is in dataset i have all ids in table at 0 index, names at 1 index and so on.. i want all arranged in one table of dataset so i can bind it to datafrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by iterating on elements in the xml and creating List of Class Objects this way :

```
public List<Population> GetData()
    {
        DataSet ds =null;

        List<Population> populationList = new List<Population>();

        string url = "http://www.lyfechannel.com/channels/WIN946/get_population.php";

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());


        XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//population");

        XmlNodeList currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//name");

        var objPopulation = new Population[currentNodes.Count];

        if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < currentNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                objPopulation[i] = new Population();
                //objPopulation[i].Name = currentNodes[i].InnerText;

            }

        }


        XmlNodeList idNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//id");

        if (idNodeList.Count != 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < idNodeList.Count; i++)
            {
                objPopulation[i] = new Population();
                objPopulation[i].ID = idNodeList[i].InnerText;


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//name");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int ij = 0; ij < currentNodes.Count; ij++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[ij].Name = currentNodes[ij].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//hcp");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < currentNodes.Count; j++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[j].HCP = currentNodes[j].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//symptoms");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int k = 0; k < currentNodes.Count; k++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[k].Symptoms = currentNodes[k].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//range");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int l = 0; l < currentNodes.Count; l++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[l].Range = currentNodes[l].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//last7");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int m = 0; m < currentNodes.Count; m++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[m].Last7 = currentNodes[m].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//connect");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int n = 0; n < currentNodes.Count; n++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[n].Connect = currentNodes[n].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//engage");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int o = 0; o < currentNodes.Count; o++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[o].Engage = currentNodes[o].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//daysin");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int p = 0; p < currentNodes.Count; p++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[p].DaysIn = currentNodes[p].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//education");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int q = 0; q < currentNodes.Count; q++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[q].Education = currentNodes[q].InnerText;

                    }

                }


                currentNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//recco");


                if (currentNodes.Count != 0)
                {

                    for (int r = 0; r < currentNodes.Count; r++)
                    {

                        objPopulation[r].Recco = currentNodes[r].InnerText;

                    }

                }

                populationList.Add(objPopulation[i]);

            }

        }

        MyGrid.ItemsSource = populationList;


    }
```

and here is my Class code:

```
class Population
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string HCP { get; set; }
    public string Symptoms { get; set; }
    public string Range { get; set; }
    public string Last7 { get; set; }
    public string Connect { get; set; }
    public string Engage { get; set; }
    public string DaysIn { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public string Recco { get; set; }

}
```